Smart Contract for Gasless ERC-20 Transfers
I'm building an app where I want to pay the transaction fees for ERC-20 token transfers between user's wallets that don't necessarily have ETH. I know of standards like EIP-2612, which provides permit, but I want to support pre-existing ERC-20 tokens that don't have such a method. Similar questions have been asked, and from my research, one way is to first transfer some ETH to the sender's wallet to pay for gas, for every transaction. However, I don't want to do this because gas costs are hard to estimate, and I risk sending too much or too little.
I came up with the idea to add my own kind of meta-transaction layer in between with a smart contract, but I am new to smart contract development so I'm not sure if it would work. Basically, my contract would be like the following:
contract GaslessTransfer {
    function gaslessTransfer(
        address token,
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount,
        uint8 v,
        bytes32 r,
        bytes32 s
    ) public {
        // verify signature according to EIP-712, keep track of a sequential nonce...

        // then:
        IERC20(token).transferFrom(from, to, amount);
    }
}

Then, before I use the contract for the first time for each token and user, I call approve(<GaslessTransfer address>, type(uint).max) from the sender. This way, I only have to transfer them ETH once, rather than for every transaction.
Is this idea sound? I am wary of the infinite allowance. If there is a security issue with this, can I fix it/are there any alternatives?

You're thinking in the right direction.
Do check Uniswap's Permit2 contract, it takes this direction to also support tokens that don't natively support EIP2612.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

Thanks, I did actually end up solving it similarly. Permit2 was indeed my starting point.


but I want to support pre-existing ERC-20 tokens that don't have such a method

Not possible.
However you might be able to do it with ERC-4337 account abstraction. There are no widespread examples yet.

Thanks, I looked into account abstraction, but its complexity was infeasible for my needs. Yes, it is impossible to completely use meta-transactions. However, I was able to use my contract to only require one approve, which is good enough for me.
